# Mac Mini mid-2010 - fan spins up for a second, then stops

Tags: mac

I have a Mac Mini 4.1 mid-2010 with High Sierra installed currently. Everything works perfectly, however I noticed that the fan is regularly spinning up for just a second, then stops again for several seconds and the cycle repeats. Trying to set a fan speed manually with macsfancontrol doesn't change the behaviour at all.

However the app seems to be able to read out the fan speed correctly, it shows 0rpm when the fan isn't spinning and a few hundred rpm when it's briefly turning on.

The fan is able to spin freely, there is nothing physically blocking it. I cleaned the computer and added new thermal compound to the heatsink. All cables are connected and there doesn't seem to be any damage to the mainboard.

What could cause this strange behaviour?

Comment: Did you have a look at the CPU temperature?

Comment: Yes, it's going up to 80°C... I'm thinking that's a temperature where the fan should definitely kick in.

Comment: Did you remove the dust from the case? Minis tend to accumulate a lot of it over time.

Comment: Yes, I completely cleaned it and added new thermal compound as well.

Comment: Might be worth adding these details to the question.

Comment: Good tip, will do!

Comment: "..new thermal compound as well." Without putting this Mini on a test bench, I would guess there is a sensor that's not reporting correctly, causing the erratic behavior. Perhaps there's thermal compound not where it is supposed to be, or conversely, not enough where it should be.

Comment: The issues was there before I added the new thermal compound as well, I made sure to clean up any residue of the old thermal compound and added a drop of it to the gpu and cpu. How could I check if any sensors are reporting nonsense from within the OS?

Comment: Download [iStat Menus](https://bjango.com/mac/istatmenus/), which can put a slew of information in your menu bar about internal temperature sensor measurements, (and many other things.) _Disclaimer:_ I'm a very happy user of iStat menus. No financial or other ties to Bjango Pty Ltd.

Comment: Did that. All the temperature values seem plausible (between 40°C and 80°C for the CPU Die and CPU Heatsink depending on load), exhaust at 0 rpm for most of the time except for when it's briefly spinning up.

Comment: Trying to set the fan speed manually to 5500 rpm does not increase the fan speed or make it spin continuously.